# Mockito exception

Tags: java, exception, junit, mockito

There is test code which thorws exception and I can't understand - why?

Exception:

```
    org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException:
```

Test code:

```
 @Test
    public void testUpdateBookingFormData() throws Exception {
        when(registrantFormService.getRegistrantFormByUUID(any(String.class))).thenReturn(registrantForm);
        when(bookingService.getById(any(Long.class))).thenReturn(booking);
        when(eventFieldRepository.findByEventIdOrderBySortIndexAsc(any(Long.class))).thenReturn(eventFieldList);
        when(registrantAggregateService.getRegistrantDataAggregate(any(RegistrantKey.class))).thenReturn(registrantAggregate);
        when(bookingFormStrategiesFactory.chooseStrategy(any(Long.class))).thenReturn(bookingFormStrategy);
        when(bookingFormValidatorsFactory.getValidatorForForm(any(Booking.class))).thenReturn(validator);
        when(validator.validate(any(BookingFormBean.class))).thenReturn(true);
        when(bookingFormStrategy.getFormByKey(any(Booking.class), any(RegistrantKey.class))).thenReturn(bookingFormBean);

        BookingFormsCollectionBean bookingFormsCollectionBean = bookingFormsService.updateBookingFormData(eq(booking.getKey().getVisitorId()), anyString(), anyMapOf(String.class, String[].class));

        assertThat(bookingFormsCollectionBean, is(IsNull.notNullValue()));
    }
```

What I am doing wrong?

UPD: Full code http://pastebin.com/rprLG8Nt

UPD2: This full exception message:

```
  org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
1 matchers expected, 3 recorded:
-> at com.evm.front.service.logic.bookingprocess.BookingFormsServiceTest.testUpdateBookingFormData(BookingFormsServiceTest.java:106)
-> at com.evm.front.service.logic.bookingprocess.BookingFormsServiceTest.testUpdateBookingFormData(BookingFormsServiceTest.java:106)
-> at com.evm.front.service.logic.bookingprocess.BookingFormsServiceTest.testUpdateBookingFormData(BookingFormsServiceTest.java:106)

This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
    //incorrect:
    someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
    //correct:
    someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));

For more info see javadoc for Matchers class.


    at com.evm.front.service.logic.bookingprocess.BookingFormsService.updateBookingFormData(BookingFormsService.java:202)
    at com.evm.front.service.logic.bookingprocess.BookingFormsServiceTest.testUpdateBookingFormData(BookingFormsServiceTest.java:106)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
    at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
```

Comment: How are you creating the mock objects?

Comment: @BilboBaggins well, I am add all my code in this http://pastebin.com/rprLG8Nt

Comment: What's the full exception? I.e. which line is the problematic one?

Comment: Please indicate which line is throwing the exception, your full exception message, and the lines of your stack trace that reference your test class; otherwise, it's very hard to debug. Also, please check that the method calls within each of your calls to `when` is for a non-final method, as any final methods will not be mocked and instead their matchers will contribute to an InvalidUseOfMatchersException.

Comment: What do you intend to do with this code? :`BookingFormsCollectionBean bookingFormsCollectionBean = bookingFormsService.updateBookingFormData(eq(booking.getKey().getVisitorId()), anyString(), anyMapOf(String.class, String[].class));`

Comment: bookingFormsService.updateBookingFormData(eq(booking.getKey().getVisitorId()), anyString(), anyMapOf(String.class, String[].class)); in this line you are passing something like booking.getKey() and getVisitorId() in place of these you should try with Mockito.any() or change the anyString() and anyMapOf to any other parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception points us to line `106`. But that line has two matchers while the exception complains about three. However, the next non-empty line, line `108` is strange: it includes matchers without a `when()` call. You can try to invoke it with actual values, something like this:

```
BookingFormsCollectionBean bookingFormsCollectionBean = bookingFormsService.
    updateBookingFormData(booking.getKey().getVisitorId(), "salala", Collections.EMPTY_MAP);
```

You can later use more specific data to feed this test with.